# ContentDocument ID instead of its title returned from contentdocumentlink query in apex soql

Tags: apex

I am trying to get the ContentDocument title and description along with the linkedEntity name from the below soql query, but the IDs of contentDocument and LinkedEntity are returned instead of the field name. I can't refer them using relationship. Any suggestions?

```java
myContentDocLink = [
    SELECT contentdocumentlink.id, contentdocument.title, contentdocument.description, 
      linkedentity.name, linkedentity.id  
    FROM ContentDocumentLink
    WHERE linkedentityid IN :lstLinkedEntityID
        AND sharetype = 'V' 
        AND contentdocument.filetype = 'SNOTE'
]
```

Comment: Your SOQL seems to be returning the appropriate fields  contentdocument.title, contentdocument.description and linkedentity.name . What kind of records is in lstLinkedEntityID ? Have you tried to debug the result of the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query seems to be correct, it should return `ContentDocument's`  `Title` and `Description` along with `LinkedEntity's` `Name`.

If you are verifying this by debugging `myContentDocLink`variable, then you won't see the values of related objects fields in the debug logs.

If you want to check the values of related objects field values i.e. in your case `ContentDocument` and `LinkedEntity`, then you will have to debug it explicitly like below

```
system.debug('Content Document Title : ' + myContentDocLink[0].ContentDocument.Title);
system.debug('Content Document Description :  ' + myContentDocLink[0].ContentDocument.Description);
system.debug('Linked Entitys Name : ' + myContentDocLink[0].LinkedEntity.Name);
```

Below debug would debug only the values of the fields that are part of `ContentDocumentLink` object and not related objects.

```
system.debug(myContentDocLink):
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay for your reply. Yes i tried that, but i got thrown an error saying variable does not exist: ContentDocument. Really don't know how to proceed...

Comment: My mistake, your SOQL will return list, so you cannot use the dot notation directly on list variable. You will have to use the index to debug it. Updated the answer

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't realized it as well!! Just quickly tried    system.debug(myContentDocLink[0].ContentDocument.title); and it works. thanks!

Comment: i have a follow up question. I am about to write the test class for this. However, i kept getting method is not visible error message. I doesn't see to understand RetrieveProjectNotesController is the outer class and TaskWrapper is the inner class. I add @TestVisible in the TaskWrapper inner class already.

Comment: Hi  @Zhang, To help you on this problem, we will need to look at the code that you have written. Hence  I would suggest you to post a separate question for this with the relevant code.

Comment: i got the answer. I put @TestVisible in the inner class declaration, as soon as i put it along the Constructor, and it works.

Comment: That's great !!